# my page does not refresh automatically - laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I don't know what the error is, the URL **(url: "/ultimo-pedidox")** finds it correctly but it doesn't refresh in the view

```
@extends('store/template')
@section('content')

<div style="margin-top: 55px;" class="">
  <div class="@if($tracking->status != "Pedido Cancelado") bg-primary @else bg-danger @endif ht-700 bd-0">
    <div style="padding-top: 100px;" class="">
      <div class="text-center tx-medium bd-0 tx-white @if($tracking->status != "Pedido Cancelado") bg-primary @else bg-danger @endif">
        <h1 style="padding-top: 15px;">Estado de mi último Pedido:</h1>
      </div>
               
      <div id="bordesestado" class="text-center tx-medium bd-0 tx-white @if($tracking->status != "Pedido Cancelado") bg-primary @else bg-danger @endif">
        @include('store.order.ultimo-pedidox', $tracking)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@stop
    
@section('script')
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ultimo-pedidox",
        success: function(response) {
          if (response && response.html != "") {
            $("#bordesestado").html(response.html);
          }
        }
      });
    }, 1000);  
  });
</script>
@endsection
```

**I tried, changing id but it doesn't work either, how can I find the error?**

help pls

Comment: maybe check your browser console??

Comment: console does not show error, loads normally

Answer (score -1):

Maybe if you use this to get the correct url
url: "{{ url('/ultimo-pedidox') }}"